Are hidden markov models limited to just bigrams?
I am reading Jurafsky's Appendix A on Hidden Markov Models and he mentions the Markov Model representing a bigram model given the Markov assumption.

This Markov chain should be familiar; in fact, it represents a bigram
language model, with each edge expressing the probability p(w_i|w_j)!

Does this mean that HMMs can't work with other n-gram models?

No, HMMs can work with any N-grams, but it becomes quickly intractable if you have large N:

Unigram model:

conditional transition probability: p(w_i | w_1,...,w_{i-1}) = p(w_i|w_{i-1})
transition table size: (#dim)^2


Bigram model:

conditional transition probability: p(w_i | w_1,...,w_{i-1}) = p(w_i|w_{i-1},w_{i-2})
transition table size: (#dim)^3


N-grams model:

conditional transition probability: p(w_i|w_{i-1}, ..., w{i-N})
transition table size: (#dim)^(N+1)



